# Remove .php in apache called

Tags: php, apache, jelastic

I would like to remove .php extension for uri calls. 
In Linux pure machine, i can make this editing .htaccess and enable mod_rewrite. Can i make this in JElastic ?

Example: http://mydomain/company.php , i would like to called http://mydomain/company

I tried to edit .htaccess but doesn't work.

My question is how to detect this: /company.php and change it to /company directly
Thanks

Comment: post your .htaccess. Make sure that .htaccess overwrite is enabled in your apache config. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: Yes this is possible. Please post your code that didn't work + any error messages. Also consider completely disabling .htaccess since you have full access to the Apache conf files... (better performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code, I've been using this hope this helps

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

remove .php like in home.php `<a href ="home" ></a>`